# Error on creating index on table in sql server, how to fix it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

On creating **clustered index** on table in SQL SERVER 2008 (LIVE DB) got above error. Total records in table is **1046789**.

I have created same index on test db with same number of records and it successfully created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is "what can I do to fix this?"

Making that assumption:

> Perform the following tasks to
>   alleviate the problem:
>
> Locate the transaction that is holding
>   the lock on the required resource, if
>   possible. Use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
>   and sys.dm_tran_locks dynamic
>   management views.
>
> If the transaction is still holding
>   the lock, terminate that transaction
>   if appropriate.
>
> Execute the query again.
>
> If this error occurs frequently change
>   the lock time-out period or modify the
>   offending transactions so that they
>   hold the lock for less time.

And if that doesn't work:

> In this scenario following changes
>   must be done in the offending
>   transaction: 1) Modify the Transaction
>   use query hints (use
>   RECOMPILE,MAXDOPhints) 2) Run big
>   Transaction in smaller transactions.
>   3) Upgrade Hardware if possible.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337412.aspx) and [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/25/sql-server-alternate-fix-error-1222-lock-request-time-out-period-exceeded/)

Answer (score 0):

Use following commands to find out exactly what processes are holding the exclusive locks on your table. FYI, creation of any type index must put exclusive locks on a table due to the complexity of the task. In clustered indexes the data are re-arranged physically on the disk. No access will be available on the table unless you specify the option ONLINE = OFF at index creation.

Before running, REPLACE DATABASE_NAME, DB_ID, OBJ_ID and SPID with real integer values.

> CREATE TABLE  tempdb..#temp_lock
> (spid int, dbid int, ObjId int, IndId
> int, Type nvarchar(30), Resource
> nvarchar(100), Mode  nvarchar(10),
> Status nvarchar(30))
>
> Use **DATABASE_NAME**
>
> GO
>
> insert into  tempdb..#temp_lock exec master..sp_lock
>
> select spid, ObjId, mode, name from
> tempdb..#temp_lock as a inner join
> [test2]..sysobjects as b on a.ObjId=
> b.id where a.dbid = **DB_ID**

Identify The Spid which is holding "X" mode locks on your table.
Note down **ObjId** and **SPID** values from previous query.

Find out what the locking Spid is executing.

> dbcc inputbuffer (**SPID**)

**or more detailed:**

> DECLARE @Handle binary(252)
>
> SELECT @Handle = sql_handle FROM master..sysprocesses WHERE spid = **SPID**
>
> SELECT * FROM ::fn_get_sql(@Handle)  Go

Decide whether to terminate the process or commit the transaction if you know who (user) is executing.

> KILL **SPID**

Create the index again.